# Is that the correct way to schedule a daily job?

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler

I have to schedule mails to be sent every day at certain time, and I would like to have an experienced opinion.
What I want to know, is if this is the correct (best) manner to do this kind of thing, using Quartz Scheduler:

**# Code**

```
    public static void startScheduler(){
        SchedulerFactory sf = new StdSchedulerFactory();
        try {
            Scheduler sched = sf.getScheduler();

            JobDetail job = newJob(SendDocumentsMailJob.class)
                .withIdentity("sendMailJob", "group1")
                .build();

            Date startTime = todayAt(6,0,0);

            SimpleTrigger trigger = newTrigger() 
                .withIdentity("everyDayAt6oClock", "group1")
                .startAt(startTime)
                .withSchedule(simpleSchedule()
                    .withIntervalInHours(24) // is this correct?
                    .repeatForever())
                .build();

            sched.scheduleJob(job,trigger);

            sched.start();
            System.out.println("Starting at: "+new Date());
            System.out.println("Next trigger fires at: "+startTime);

            // sched.shutdown(); // is this correct?

        }catch (SchedulerException ex) { ex.printStackTrace();} 
        //catch (InterruptedException ex) { ex.printStackTrace();} 
        catch (Exception ex) { ex.printStackTrace();} 
    }
```

I didn't find any method to set a daily interval, so I used: **withIntervalInHours(24)**, is that correct?

The scheduler will run indefinitely, so I don't have to call **shutdown()**, correct?

Thanks,

Comment: What environment are you running this in (os/server)

Comment: It will run on a CentOS 5.9./ Java 1.7./ Glassfish 3.1.2.2. web server.

Comment: why don't you use the native os scheduler? i Think running agent-like modules are not good idea to run in server environments

Comment: The application user have no access to the server, but to the web application control panel via login, there he can change the mail sending settings (sending time and frequency for example), but only thru the apps control panel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are running on a web server, this is indeed a viable way to do this.  Don't call shutdown as that will stop the firing of Triggers.